# How to make the terminal autoclose when a command runs successfully?

Tags: command-line

I want to make the terminal autoclose when a command runs successfully. It shouldn't autoclose if the command produces some error.

#### For example:

If I run `sudo apt-get install vlc`, the terminal should be closed automatically if the VLC package installs successfully. Otherwise, it shouldn't close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following command

```
bind 'RETURN: ";if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then exit; fi;\n"'
```

if you need it work everytime when you start new session, add this command to `~/.bashrc` file, and then run `source ~/.bashrc` to make it take effect immediately.

then if you enter

```
ls
```

it will be automatically replaced by

```
ls; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then exit; fi;
```

Comment: where i have to use `bind 'RETURN: ";if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then exit; fi;\n"'` command?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Just run this command in your terminal. If you would like it work everwhere, put it into .bashrc.

Comment: i want it to work for all the commands.

Comment: It should. Have you tried it?(put this command in .bashrc will make it take effect for all command)

Comment: pls edit your answer for adding the above command to .bashrc and source it to work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Most of the time, you don't want the terminal to exit after **any** command, just some of the time. If this is the case, putting it in bashrc is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `&& exit` after the command you want to quit the terminal:

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc && exit
```

Explanation:

```
&&      Run the next command if the preceding command exits with 0 (success)
exit    Exit the terminal or script
```

This is probably better than exiting if *any* command succeeds; you probably want to run more than one command in a terminal.

---

If you're *really* sure the terminal should exit after every successful command, use this in your `.bashrc`:

```
bind 'RETURN: "\C-e ; [[ $? == 0 ]] && exit ;
"'
```

(ensure that the closing quotes are on a new line)